# How do you build FFmpeg for Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, mac-catalyst

With XCode 11 and macOS 10.15 (Catalina), you can now build iPad apps to run on a Mac by checking `Mac` in the General settings of the target. I have an iPhone/iPad app that uses ffmpeg. When I try to build it for the Mac I get this linker error:

> Building for Mac Catalyst, but the linked library 'libavformat.a' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. You may need to restrict the platforms for which this library should be linked in the target editor, or replace it with an XCFramework that supports both platforms.

So my question is, how do you build a static library for *Mac Catalyst* or create an XCFramework for ffmpeg? I am using build-ffmpeg.sh from **FFmpeg-iOS-build-script** on GitHub to bulild the ffmpeg static libraries for iOS.

Comment: See https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script/pull/147